# Как держать элемент в RecyclerView, на котором находится фокуc, по центру?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Управление приложением происходит с пульта. Элемент, который находится в фокусе, выделяется другим background'ом. Как сделать так, чтобы элемент с фокусом всегда был по центру, кроме случаев, когда мы в начале / конце списка - там нужно доходить до начала/конца?

Конфигурация RecyclerView следующая:

1. Вертикальный LinearLayoutManager
2. stable ids
3. fixed size
4. У item'ов на parent'e (a.k.a. ConstraintLayout) стоит `android:focusable=true`

SnapHelper, насколько я понимаю, работает только с "выбранным" элементом.
Прошу помочь, или хотя бы подсказать в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Первая мысль - слушатель фокуса и программный скролл до середины/верха/низа

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510142/14840395 CenterSnapHelper из этого ответа решает мой вопрос!